# Android App not displayed in Tablet Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, tablet

I have an android app which works well with Mobile phones. I recently released the app for tablets too but it seems the app is not visible from Samsung Galaxy Tab S3. Below is my manifest.

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="<package-name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="<package-name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The Samsung Galaxy Tab S3 has Sim Card, SD Card, Camera and all the other features which are being used by the app. So, it should be visible in the play store.

I checked in Nexus 7 and Nexus 9. It says "Your device isn't compatible with this version."

Answer (score 1):

You  could try the below ideas. I don't know for sure if they will work, but they are worth a try.

1. If you are trying to support phones and tablets, i assume you don't care which screen size they have. Try removing the `<supports-screens />` section. This will remove an unnecessary device restriction.
2. Ensure you have uploaded at least 1 screen shot to the PlayStore, from tablets. (into the correct tablet screenshot area). This allows it to be classed as tablet friendly.

> For your app to be showcased in the 'Designed for tablets' list in the Play Store, you need to upload at least one 7-inch and one 10-inch screenshot. If you previously uploaded screenshots, make sure to move them into the right area.

3. There is a section in the developer console.`Release Management -> Device catalog`. It will actually tell you all the devices your app Does support, and Doesn't support. Finding the device in question, and clicking it, should hopefully highlight why it is not supported.